# how to add Use token/cookie to authorize the user in AWS Video Streaming with Lambda & Media Convert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, aes, http-live-streaming

**how to add  Use token/cookie to authorize the user**

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t83t2CNTZyU
> https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-simple-vod-workflow/blob/master/7-MediaConvertJobLambda/README.md

Using above video I have done successfully conversion of my video to HLS streaming it worked fine. **now i want to add encryption key whenever video converted into ts chunk i want add encryption key in output bucket**

how to add in lambda expresion which i used for conversion Ref:

> https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-simple-vod-workflow/blob/master/7-MediaConvertJobLambda/lambda.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref:

```
  https://github.com/aws-samples/
    amazon-cloudfront-protecting-hls-manifest-with-signed-url
```

Above url download yaml to create **aws cloudformation** generate following distribution

[image]